# Visual studio: Can and cannot access a namespace

Tags: asp.net, .net, oracle, visual-studio, warnings

I'm getting a strange warning when hovering over an OracleConnection object in visual studio. It doesn't seem to stop my website from working fine, but the warning bugs me.

It seems that the class and Oracle.DataAcces.Client namespace is both visible and not visible to my project at the same time.

Here are some pictures:

[image: I don't have the reputation to post images]

I have no idea what is causing this; I already have the Oracle.DataAcces reference in my project references. What I suspect that is happening is a bug that would cause my project name to interfere with my namespace, but that doesn't seem to be it.

I tried changing my namespace name and project name to different things, and I still get the same result.

And for some reason the project shows up twice in the navigation bar:

[image: Picture of the project part of the navigation bar]

Comment: I tried that, said that I didn't have enough rep to post images, anyway thanks for the edit.

Comment: is this 2017RC?... try "Clean Solution"

Comment: Is your project targeting both the full .NET Framework and .NET CORE?  I wonder if this is saying projectX is available for full .NET and not for .NET CORE?

Comment: @SteveKennedy is there a way I can see that? I just updated the post since I found some workaround/solution but I am still curious as what is causing this.

Comment: @T.S. I don't know about 2017RC as I use 2015(enterprise) and 2013(ultimate).

Comment: Thanks for wanting to supply the answer you found. Please re-post that as an answer (below) rather than as an edit to the question. Your answer is available [in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42589823/revisions) if you want to copy-paste it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

After some research, usage of the scientific method and throwing things are rotating blades and seeing what sticks this is what I think might be happening, and I think I found a "solution/workaround" to it.

It appears as Visual Studio is trying to add some temporary DLL/reference to a temporary DLL/project containing all the namespaces that aren't my Web Application's Directory.

Here is what makes me think that this is happening:

1. When opening the Object Browser <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>, There are multiple instances of the projectX Project. Using Dot peek I determined that one of them was the compiled version of my project and the other is some weird project without the main namespace (projectX): [image]
2. Cleaning the project sometimes work, but the best solution so far has been to go into the solution and files delete the bin and obj folder from my project folder and restart visual studio.
3. Only using the projectX namespace with no sub-namespaces doesn't fix the problem all. The additional projectX instance in the object browser contains the same thing as the normal one, minus the files and web page objects in my main directory.

#### So here is my solution:

Create a class library in the solution and put all your classes in it. Then move the references that your class needs to your new class library. Finally, add a project reference to the Web Application pointing to the class library.

It looks like I manage to find a fix but, but I'm going to have to try it for longer to make sure of it.

---

### Follow up

It appears that the solution I found works very well and won't cause the problem to happen again, therefore I recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the version of the Debugger matched with the version of the Oracle.DataAcces.Client library? That is, for e.g., if you're using x64 bit version Debugger then you should make sure the dll file is also x64.  I was having trouble accessing this reference today, and this fixed it. Hope this helps!

Comment: I did check that, same error. I also switched to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client but I still get the same error, the only way to solve this is to do what I did in my solution and create a dedicated class library.